# 404 Not Found - Github Oauth App request access to Github Enterprise

Tags: github, oauth, http-status-code-404, github-enterprise

My app is attempting to get an auth token from a users github, that we use later. Right now its working when the base URL is just https://github.com, for /login/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. But once the base url changes to the enterprise hostname ( ie git.example.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX ), it gives me a 404 error.

So..

- https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXX WORKING
- https://[enterprisehostname]/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXX 404
  Not Found

I can't figure out why the 404 error comes up!

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can tell, it's a 404 because that api doesn't exist for enterprise. you should use the normal oauth flow and just use your enterprise user to authenticate. https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-oauth-apps

> You can connect your GitHub Enterprise identity to third-party applications using OAuth.

if you are wanting to restrict access to your app to people in your enterprise account, you will need to filter them out later. you should be able to request access to the organizations they belong to and reject anyone who isn't part of your organization

Comment: So i was attempting to use the flow outlined here: https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.20/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps/

It makes it seem like you can use this flow with enterprise server, not just enterprise cloud. The difficulty is i don't actually need to auth a user for my app, i just need that token, and would prefer to not require a user to generate one and provide it manually.

Comment: Sorry i meant this: https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.20/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ur secret and client id key both are correct